# Format the string using sprintf

Tags: php, printf

I have this string:

```
"[\"form\",\"form-elements\"], [\"company\",\"asdasd\"], [\"cod_postal\",\"051768\"], [\"recaptcha_challenge_field\",\"03AHJ_VuvJZjfMzRQolI_QhGijJqAEcRPswuz9l68I6VStJzTbuK4ilos06TIQKVsIy2vpe1PEq-Q5KBVlZ5xt4HM5VoJSWUgFTGVbtbmARtKiMvO4WZh57X0-QVDyQ5Lq-ZM8rMqB5O2-rCbnyw_UAGbbV1ZElsI4kuLk4ei6mzLtqgcU2VAR64tySiKPARDtahiTBKWePH2rjKO6KUBQTRE49TMjIGb5hg8sbYguKBSUrRF6G86b89M\"], [\"recaptcha_response_field\",\"168\"]"
```

This string was formated form an array using this code:

```
function arrayDisplay($input)
{
    return implode(
        ', ',
        array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                return sprintf('["%s","%s"]', $k, $v);
            },
            $input,
            array_keys($input)
        )
    );
}
```

And encoded using :

```
$xml_array = arrayDisplay($_POST);
$xml_encode = json_encode($xml_array);
```

And this is the array in $_POST variable:

```
array (size=5)
  'form' => string 'form-elements' (length=13)
  'company' => string 'asdasd' (length=6)
  'cod_postal' => string '051768' (length=6)
  'recaptcha_challenge_field' => string '03AHJ_VuvJZjfMzRQolI_QhGijJqAEcRPswuz9l68I6VStJzTbuK4ilos06TIQKVsIy2vpe1PEq-Q5KBVlZ5xt4HM5VoJSWUgFTGVbtbmARtKiMvO4WZh57X0-QVDyQ5Lq-ZM8rMqB5O2-rCbnyw_UAGbbV1ZElsI4kuLk4ei6mzLtqgcU2VAR64tySiKPARDtahiTBKWePH2rjKO6KUBQTRE49TMjIGb5hg8sbYguKBSUrRF6G86b89M' (length=249)
  'recaptcha_response_field' => string '168' (length=3)
```

First I want to wrap the entire string replacing "" with [] :

```
[[\"form\",\"form-elements\"], [\"company\",\"asdasd\"], [\"cod_postal\",\"051768\"], [\"recaptcha_challenge_field\",\"03AHJ_VuvJZjfMzRQolI_QhGijJqAEcRPswuz9l68I6VStJzTbuK4ilos06TIQKVsIy2vpe1PEq-Q5KBVlZ5xt4HM5VoJSWUgFTGVbtbmARtKiMvO4WZh57X0-QVDyQ5Lq-ZM8rMqB5O2-rCbnyw_UAGbbV1ZElsI4kuLk4ei6mzLtqgcU2VAR64tySiKPARDtahiTBKWePH2rjKO6KUBQTRE49TMjIGb5hg8sbYguKBSUrRF6G86b89M\"], [\"recaptcha_response_field\",\"168\"]]
```

And exclude `[\"form\",\"form-elements\"]` , `[\"recaptcha_challenge_field\",\"03AHJ_VuvJZjfMzRQolI_QhGijJqAEcRPswuz9l68I6VStJzTbuK4ilos06TIQKVsIy2vpe1PEq-Q5KBVlZ5xt4HM5VoJSWUgFTGVbtbmARtKiMvO4WZh57X0-QVDyQ5Lq-ZM8rMqB5O2-rCbnyw_UAGbbV1ZElsI4kuLk4ei6mzLtqgcU2VAR64tySiKPARDtahiTBKWePH2rjKO6KUBQTRE49TMjIGb5hg8sbYguKBSUrRF6G86b89M\"]` and `[\"recaptcha_response_field\",\"168\"]`

What I can use to do that and how ?

Comment: Can you specify your goal? For example: what I *think* you are trying to achieve is dropping the key-value entries for the keys 'form','recaptcha_challenge_field' and 'recaptcha_response_field' so that they do not appear in the key-value-map in the $_POST variable. I this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must filter the input. After filtering it you just return the json encoded string:

```
function arrayDisplay($input)
{
    $input = array_filter($input, function ($key) {
        return !in_array($key, array('form', 'recaptcha_challenge_field', 'recaptcha_response_field'));
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    return json_encode(array($input));
}
```

If you still want to return the key-value pairs separated by comma then keep the original implode function and concatenate the result with the squared brackets:

```
function arrayDisplay($input)
{
    $input = array_filter($input, function ($key) {
        return !in_array($key, array('form', 'recaptcha_challenge_field', 'recaptcha_response_field'));
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    return '[' . implode(
        ', ',
        array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                return sprintf('["%s","%s"]', $k, $v);
            },
            $input,
            array_keys($input)
        )
    ) . ']';
}
```

Please note that `$xml_encode = json_encode($xml_array);` makes no sense as the returned string is "almost" a valid json encoded string (in the original function). If this is your intention then you must use the first function I wrote and remove that line of code that is encoding again the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from your *$_POST* array, and take the keys from it you really need:

```php
$input = $_POST;
unset($input["form"]);
unset($input["recaptcha_challenge_field"]);
unset($input["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

Now that *$input* array looks like this:

```php
array(
  "company" => "asdasd",
  "cod_postal" => "051768"
);
```

Then, I would change the definition of your *arrayDisplay* function without altering its functionality, by splitting it into 2:

```php
function arrayPairs($input) {
    return array_map(
        function ($v, $k) {
            return [$k,$v];
        },
        $input,
        array_keys($input)
    );
}

function arrayDisplay($input) {
    return implode (", ", array_map('json_encode', arrayPairs($input)));
}
```

This *arrayDisplay* function still returns the same values as before, but you can now also call *arrayPairs* without conversion to string. Instead you would do that conversion with *json_encode* which gives exactly the output you want:

```php
echo json_encode(arrayPairs($input));
```

This outputs:

> [["company","asdasd"],["cod_postal","051768"]]

NB: If you don't use the *arrayDisplay* function for any other purpose, then you can do away with it. This solution only uses the function *arrayPairs*.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and ended up with this:

```
 function arrayDisplay($input)
{
    $goodKeys = array_diff(array_keys($input), array('form', 'recaptcha_challenge_field', 'recaptcha_response_field'));
var_dump($goodKeys);

    $data = [];
    foreach ($goodKeys as $goodKey) {
       $data[$goodKey] = $input[$goodKey];
    }
    return '[' . implode(
        ', ',
        array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                return sprintf('["%s","%s"]', $k, $v);
            },
            $data,
            array_keys($data)
        )
    ) . ']';
}
```

but now there is one more problem, I need to get rid of "" this 2 from the start/end of the string:
from this:

```
"[[\"company\",\"123\"], [\"cod_postal\",\"051768\"]]"
```

to this:

```
[[\"company\",\"123\"], [\"cod_postal\",\"051768\"]]
```